# Deploying Gunicorn using subpath in NGINX

Tags: python, nginx, gunicorn

According to [this](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html) tutorial, there is section below that says this.

You must now configure your web proxy to send traffic to the new Gunicorn socket. Edit your nginx.conf to include the following:

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:**

```
...
http {
    server {
        listen          8000;
        server_name     127.0.0.1;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn/socket;
        }
    }
}
...
```

What I want to do is use `location /mysubpath`. How should I do it? 
I'm using `mysubpath` since I have 2 different projects running on the same server.
Something like this.

```
...
    http {
        server {
            listen          8000;
            server_name     127.0.0.1;
            location /mysubpath {
                proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn/socket;
            }
        }
    }
    ...
```

Usually, we do `proxy_pass  http://someip:someport/;` but in my case, it might require a different approach. Can someone please help.